# Is there no predefined saturation policy for ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice*, and was puzzled by the statement about ThreadPoolExecutor as below:

> There is no predefined saturation policy to make execute block when the work
>   queue is full.

However, the author also refer to `abort` as the default policy.

So whats's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the java doc:

> New tasks submitted in method execute(Runnable) will be rejected when
>   the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor uses
>   finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity, **and is
>   saturated**. In either case, the execute method invokes the
>   RejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(Runnable,
>   ThreadPoolExecutor) method of its RejectedExecutionHandler.

And there are 4 different predefined handlers:

1. In the default ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy, the handler throws a runtime RejectedExecutionException upon rejection.
2. In ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy, the thread that invokes execute itself runs the task. This provides a simple feedback control mechanism that will slow down the rate that new tasks are submitted.
3. In ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy, a task that cannot be executed is simply dropped.
4. In ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy, if the executor is not shut down, the task at the head of the work queue is dropped, and then execution is retried (which can fail again, causing this to be repeated.)

So by default the AbordPolicy is used.

> It is possible to define and use other kinds of
>   RejectedExecutionHandler classes. Doing so requires some care
>   especially when policies are designed to work only under particular
>   capacity or queuing policies.

extract from ThreadPoolExecutor source code:

```
/**
 * The default rejected execution handler
 */
private static final RejectedExecutionHandler defaultHandler =
    new AbortPolicy();

public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
}

public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                          ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         threadFactory, defaultHandler);
}
```

As said by @Jiri Tousek, all of this default behavior block the caller.

Comment: And to relate to the quote in the question - none of the four predefined policies blocks the caller.

Comment: CallerRunsPolicy kind of blocks the caller by running the task. Doesnt block the caller on execute until a spot is free on the queue tho